Equivalent matrix given a constraint on elements
Assume there is a matrix which has elements with a normal distribution. How to find a matrix which every element can only be -1, 0, or 1 such that it has closest eigenvalues to the original matrix. The equivalent matrix should have the exact same shape. The matrix containing -1, 0, 1 can be multiplied by an scaled by a single scalar (like standard deviation of original matrix).

What restrictions do you want on the size of the found matrix?  Take example where original matrix is of dimension 1 and has an eigenvalue of 5.   A 5x5 matrix with all values 1 would include eigenvalue of 5.

The matrix should have the exact same shape. Added it to the question to clarify the constraints
